# Como acessar elemento DOM de dentro do model ClientesDAO.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

estou fazendo uma consulta ao banco de dados e, para exibir o resultado em um elemento #estado do formulário, o Nodejs não reconhece o document.getElementById('elemento'), nem o jQuery.

Erro:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Meu método:

```
ClientesDAO.prototype.getEstados = function(res, res){
    var fb = this._firebase.database();
    var result = fb.ref().child('estados/').orderByChild('nome');
    result.once('value', function(snapshot){
        document.getElementById("estados").innerHTML(snapshot.val());
    });
}
```

Comment: Nodejs não consegue acessar o DOM porque é server-side. Você pode renderizar um `.html` e passar uma propriedade com os dados do banco de dados ou criar um `REST API`.

Comment: Exatamente @michelmfreitas, o Rafael está certo. Você terá que enviar de alguma forma o resultado e receber no front-end. Está usando algum template engine por acaso? Fica mais fácil ajudar se puder detalhar como está a página e como está fazendo essa chamada.

Comment: Exato, vocês estão corretos, já que nada foi renderizado ainda. Estou utilizando EJS.

Porém, mesmo se eu retornar os dados com um return snapshot.val() o meu controller recebe um retorno vazio undefined. =/

Comment: Você está tendo um retorno vazio porque a leitura do Firebase acontece de forma assíncrona. Isso significa que no momento em que você retorna o `snapshot.val()` ele ainda não foi inicializado.